# Echo text from textfield

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to echo what the users puts in their textfield when their accounts are not "Activated" Like this

```
if(active == NULL);{

    //This is the methods i have tried.
    //In this example username is the name of the textfield.
    //I want the username to be displayed as what the typed in, but instead it just says "username"

    echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Please actiave your account, username we have sent you a mail with an activation link.</span>';

    /*In this example username1 is the id of the textfield.
    I want the username to be displayed as what the typed in, but instead it just says "username"*/

    echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Please activate your account, username1 we have sent you a mail with an activation link.</span>';




    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: fetch that username from database then display error message according to that.     Example : echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Please activate your account'. $username.' we have sent you a mail with an activation link.</span>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the POST values from the textfield ,

if your using CORE PHP you can get the post values on submit button and form post method like

```
$_POST['username'];
```

For your example do this way
(as mentioned the name of the textfield is username)

```
$username =  $_POST['username'];

echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Please actiave your account, '.$username.'  we have sent you a mail with an activation link.</span>';
```

Comment: Thank you, my friend! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: I just have to ask, If i want to do it in html like this <h2>Dear username, please check your email for an activation link</h2> How would you do that?:)

Comment: same way , echo "<h2> Dear ".$username." , please check your email for an activation link </h2> ";

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to put an id on that as well? So i can move it where i want in my css code?

Comment: for h2 tag? , yes

Comment: Okay, how?Like this ? :  echo "<h2 id="Alertnotactived"> Dear ".$username." , please check your email for an activation link </h2> ";

Comment: yes but use single quote inside h2 element , if you use echo " " ; then always inside html tag use single echo "<h2 id='demo'>" , and if you use echo ' '; then echo '<h2 id="demo">';

Comment: I get an error when i do it like this : echo '<h2 id="demo">' Dear ".$username." , please check your email for an activation link </h2> "; Whats wrong?

Comment: echo '<h2 id="demo"> Dear '.$username.' , please check your email for an activation link </h2> '; use this

Comment: It didnt work actually, the id doesnt seem to get registrered. Why?

Comment: can you paste your whole code and exactly what you want to do ?